# VS 2017 Azure Compute emulator exception System.Runtime.Serialization.SerializationException

Tags: azure, visual-studio-2017

I have azure cloud service project and whenever i try to build or run i get the below error

```
`The "DeleteCurrentDeployment" task failed unexpectedly.
System.Runtime.Serialization.SerializationException: There was an error deserializing the object of type Microsoft.ServiceHosting.Tools.DevelopmentFabric.DevFabricConfig. The data at the root level is invalid. Line 1, position 1. ---> System.Xml.XmlException: The data at the root level is invalid. Line 1, position 1.
   at System.Xml.XmlExceptionHelper.ThrowXmlException(XmlDictionaryReader reader, String res, String arg1, String arg2, String arg3)
   at System.Xml.XmlUTF8TextReader.Read()
   at System.Xml.XmlBaseReader.IsStartElement()
   at System.Xml.XmlBaseReader.IsStartElement(XmlDictionaryString localName, XmlDictionaryString namespaceUri)
   at System.Runtime.Serialization.XmlReaderDelegator.IsStartElement(XmlDictionaryString localname, XmlDictionaryString ns)
   at System.Runtime.Serialization.XmlObjectSerializer.IsRootElement(XmlReaderDelegator reader, DataContract contract, XmlDictionaryString name, XmlDictionaryString ns)
   at System.Runtime.Serialization.DataContractSerializer.InternalIsStartObject(XmlReaderDelegator reader)
   at System.Runtime.Serialization.DataContractSerializer.InternalReadObject(XmlReaderDelegator xmlReader, Boolean verifyObjectName, DataContractResolver dataContractResolver)
   at System.Runtime.Serialization.XmlObjectSerializer.ReadObjectHandleExceptions(XmlReaderDelegator reader, Boolean verifyObjectName, DataContractResolver dataContractResolver)
   --- End of inner exception stack trace ---
   at System.Runtime.Serialization.XmlObjectSerializer.ReadObjectHandleExceptions(XmlReaderDelegator reader, Boolean verifyObjectName, DataContractResolver dataContractResolver)
   at System.Runtime.Serialization.XmlObjectSerializer.ReadObject(XmlDictionaryReader reader)
   at System.Runtime.Serialization.XmlObjectSerializer.ReadObject(Stream stream)
   at Microsoft.ServiceHosting.Tools.DevelopmentFabric.DevFabricConfig.TryGetConfig(Boolean forceRefresh, DevFabricConfig& result)
   at Microsoft.ServiceHosting.Tools.DevelopmentFabric.DevFabric.InitDF(Boolean tryRunDFInit)
   at Microsoft.ServiceHosting.Tools.DevelopmentFabric.DevFabric..ctor(Boolean singleInstance)
   at Microsoft.Cct.Debugging.DevFabricService..ctor()
   at Microsoft.Cct.CctProjectNode.<>c.<get_DevFabricService>b__104_0()
   at System.Threading.LazyInitializer.EnsureInitializedCore[T](T& target, Func`1 valueFactory)
   at System.Threading.LazyInitializer.EnsureInitialized[T](T& target, Func`1 valueFactory)
   at Microsoft.Cct.CctProjectNode.get_DevFabricService()
   at Microsoft.Cct.CctBuildDeploymentTaskHost.DeleteCurrentDeployment()
   at Microsoft.CloudExtensions.MSBuildTasks.DeleteCurrentDeployment.Execute()
   at Microsoft.Build.BackEnd.TaskExecutionHost.Microsoft.Build.BackEnd.ITaskExecutionHost.Execute()
   at Microsoft.Build.BackEnd.TaskBuilder.<ExecuteInstantiatedTask>d__26.MoveNext() C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2017\Professional\MSBuild\Microsoft\VisualStudio\v15.0\Windows Azure Tools\2.9\Microsoft.WindowsAzure.targets    1218`
```

I uninstalled VS 2017 many times and installed it again and still not working and gives the same error, can anyone help please?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Could resolve the issue... After lot of analysis. It was due to the corrupted DevFabric.config file

Try replacing the C:\ProgramData\dftmp\DevFabric.config from the machine(from same path) where the azure emulator is working